# Problem attaching files via AJAX requires a recent, valid token

Tags: civimail, mosaico, ajax

I'm trying to use CiviMail and Mosaico to distribute a .pdf file to our internal distribution list. When I try to include the file as an attachment I get the error message "Attaching files via AJAX requires a recent, valid token".  The .pdf file is not one that I created, it's an announcement from one or our Board members. What can I do to get CiviMail to accept the .pdf file as an attachment?

CiviCRM 5.66.0, WordPress Version 6.4.2

Comment: I had someone report the same problem.  Did the problem occur again in the future?  My theory is that it has to do with the amount of time between pressing the "Advanced Options" button and selecting the attachment.

Comment: From an external developer I learned that,
"another Mosaico developer has this flagged as an issue: https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/598

As per the issue above, the solution is to disable the plugin:Mosaico Tweaks (mosaicotweaks) pending the developer of that extension making it compatible with Mosaico 3.x"